# In an ADT, must the structure declaration be in a separate .c file? How important is this?

Tags: c, struct, visibility, abstract-data-type

Our professor provided us with two versions of a Complex Numbers program: a DT version and an ADT version.

The DT version contains various differences from the ADT one, but what I cannot grasp is whether it's important or not where the struct declaration is placed.

In the DT version the struct declaration has been placed in a header, along with the functions' declarations; in the ADT version it has been placed in a .c file, the one where the functions are written.

Is it important where the structure is placed? From what I can imagine it would work either way, but I'm not sure since I'm just getting started with the whole ADT concept. I can't see how the file the struct is placed in can damage information hiding.

Answer (score 1):

If the fields of the type are declared in the header file, a client can access and modify the fields without going through the the functions which provide the interface to the module. One of the purposes of an abstract datatype is to be able to change the implementation, for instance the data representation, without affecting the client modules.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it important where the structure is placed?

If your program doesn't use any design but you just "hack away", then it doesn't matter. Otherwise if your program is larger and professional,  it matters for the sake of *private encapsulation*, a key term used in object-oriented design.

In case you put the struct definition in the header file, the struct members are accessible to the code using the struct, it is fully public.

In case you only put a *forward declaration* of the struct in the header file, but the actual struct definition in the .c file, then you have achieved private encapsulation. Only the .c file can access the contents of the struct. This is often referred to as *opaque type*.

This in turn means that the caller won't be able to declare an object of that struct, because the definition is not visible to the caller. They can however declare a pointer to such a struct.

Simple example:

foo.h

```
typedef struct foo foo;

foo* foo_init (int x);
void foo_free (foo* f);

int foo_get_x (const foo* f);
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h"

struct foo
{
  int x;
};

foo* foo_init (int x)
{
  foo* f = malloc(sizeof *obj);
  f->x = x;
  return f;
}

void foo_free (foo* f)
{
  free(f);
}

int foo_get_x (const foo* f)
{
  return f->x;
}
```

caller.c

```
#include "foo.h"

foo* f = foo_init(123);
printf("%d", foo_get_x(f));
foo_free(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second version (ADT) will not be visible from other translation units. So if in some translation unit there will be required a reference to the complete definition of the structure then the compiler will issue an error.

It seems that in the implementation of DT the correspomding functions refer to the ADT. So the definition of the ADT is only needed within the functions that deal with ADT. In this case there is nothing wrong.

Usualy when such an approach is used the functions defined for ADT are declared with internal linkage as static. And the functions for DT call internally the functions for ADT.

That is the definition of ADT and its functions are hidden and only visible for definitions of the functions for DT that refer the ADT and its functions.